# Outlook 2010 New Email Signature

Tags: vba, outlook, email-client

I would like to be able to create a custom "New Email" button in Outlook 2010 that sets up a new email with a different signature to the default. I have looked at various solutions from other posts but nothing that seems to fit this particular use case. Here's what I'm after :

I have a single email account that will be associated with two separate business entities each with its own signature. I would like to find a way of automatically selecting one or the other signature based on the "New Email" button used. I have added a signature for the first entity using the default signature assignment in Outlook mail properties. I have added a custom New Email button to the Ribbon which I would like to use the second entity signature on creating a new email.

Is this possible? any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Set the default signature to None.

Create two templates with the two different signatures. Create two custom buttons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865637%28v=office.15%29.aspx

```
Sub CreateFromTemplate1() 
    Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
    Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\template1.oft") 
    MyItem.Display 
End Sub 

Sub CreateFromTemplate2() 
    Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
    Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\template2.oft") 
    MyItem.Display 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There is code here to generate signatures.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm

Should look something like this.

```
Sub Mail_Outlook_With_Signature_Html_2_shortened()
'
' http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/signature.htm
'
' Don't forget to copy the function GetBoiler in the module.
' Working in Office 2000-2013

    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim SigString As String
    Dim Signature As String

    Set OutMail = CreateItem(0)

    'Change only Mysig.htm to the name of your signature
    SigString = Environ("appdata") & _
                "\Microsoft\Signatures\Mysig.htm"

    If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then

        Signature = GetBoiler(SigString)
        With OutMail
            .HTMLBody = "<br>" & Signature
            .Display
        End With

    Else

        MsgBox "Signature file not found." & vbCr & SigString

    End If

    Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub

Private Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
'Dick Kusleika
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = FSO.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    GetBoiler = ts.readall
    ts.Close
End Function
```